# Table footer doesn't page break using Apache FOP

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, apache-fop

I am generating a PDF from XML using FOP(latest dev version - 2.2). The xml consists of large complex structures and I have no control over the format or schema. Essentially my problem is that the table will not create a page break when I have a long tfoot section in the table. It breaks fine when the rows are within the tbody section and I have that working and adding a "continued" to the table title in the table header. I would like to be able to do the same but in the table footer section. 
I have researched lots of posts on Stackoverflow and the net for the answer and have tried many different scenarios, but none work for me. I've looked at: [possible stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214906/how-to-keep-table-with-header-but-allow-page-breaks-inside-table-body-in-xsl-fo) and [retrieve-table-marker example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974903/xslfo-retrieve-marker-not-valid-child/31012095#31012095) but it didn't affect my layout. I've tried many other combinations of using the keep-together properties on various constructs with no success. Here is small edited sample xml file I'm testing with I removed a lot of the content so it's not the actual file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table frame="all" id="t3" tocentry="1">
    <title>Test table retrieve markers and tfoot page break.</title>
    <tgroup align="left" cols="6">
        <colspec colname="col1" colwidth="1.17in"/>
        <colspec colname="col2" colwidth="1.17in"/>
        <colspec colname="col3" colwidth="1.19in"/>
        <colspec colname="col4" colwidth="1.17in"/>
        <colspec colname="col5" colwidth="1.17in"/>
        <colspec colname="col6" colwidth="1.17in"/>
        <thead valign="bottom">
            <row>
                <entry align="center" morerows="0" rotate="0" valign="top">Column 1</entry>
                <entry align="center" morerows="0" rotate="0" valign="top">Column 2</entry>
                <entry align="center" morerows="0" rotate="0" valign="top">Column 3</entry>
                <entry align="center" morerows="0" rotate="0" valign="top">Column 4</entry>
                <entry align="center" morerows="0" rotate="0" valign="top">Column 5</entry>
                <entry align="center" morerows="0" rotate="0" valign="top">Column 6</entry>
            </row>
        </thead>

        <tbody valign="top">
            <row>
                <entry morerows="0" rotate="0" rowsep="0" valign="top">This table has 10 footnotes in it and: <para> multiple paras, this is 1.</para><para> This is 2.</para><para> And this is 3.</para></entry>
                <entry morerows="0" rotate="0" rowsep="0" valign="top">Flanges, Caps</entry>
                <entry morerows="0" rotate="0" rowsep="0" valign="top">Ultrasonic.</entry>
                <entry morerows="0" rotate="0" rowsep="0" valign="top">dia 1 inch, see Note </entry>
                <entry morerows="0" rotate="0" rowsep="0" valign="top">dia &gt; 1 inch</entry>
                <entry morerows="0" rotate="0" rowsep="0" valign="top">=</entry>
            </row>
      <!-- Add more rows here -->

            <row>
                <entry morerows="0" rotate="0" rowsep="0" valign="top">Test more rows with footnotes<ftnote id="ftn9">
                    <para>Lots of paras here, with lots of text to make the table big. <seqlist>
                        <item><para>seqlist item 1 para 1</para><para>seqlist item 1 para 2</para><para>seqlist item 1 para 3</para></item>
                        <item><para>seqlist item 2 para 1</para><para>seqlist item 2 para 2</para><para>seqlist item 2 para 3</para></item>
                        <item><para>Here's a sublist:</para><randlist>
                            <item><para>sub-seqlist item 1 para 1</para><para>sub-seqlist item 1 para 2</para><para>sub-seqlist item 1 para 3</para></item>
                            <item><para>sub-seqlist item 2 para 1</para><para>sub-seqlist item 2 para 2</para><para>sub-seqlist item 2 para 3</para></item>
                        </randlist></item>
                    </seqlist></para>
                    <para>The item could have up to <emphasis>1.00</emphasis> inch diameter disbond or delamination in the bondline in the middle of skin.</para>
                   <!-- Add more para's here -->
                </ftnote></entry>
                <entry morerows="0" rotate="0" rowsep="0" valign="top">Flanges, Caps<ftnref xrefid="ftn9"/></entry>
                <entry morerows="0" rotate="0" rowsep="0" valign="top">Ultrasonic.</entry>
                <entry morerows="0" rotate="0" rowsep="0" valign="top">Footnote in a para but with cdata prior to para <para> now a para followed by a footnote <ftnote id="ftn10">
                    <para>The item could have up to <emphasis>1.00</emphasis> inch diameter disbond or delamination in the bondline in the middle of skin.</para>
                </ftnote></para>
                </entry>
                <entry morerows="0" rotate="0" rowsep="0" valign="top"><para> Footnote in para following entry footnote <ftnote id="ftn11">
                    <para>Footnote 8: <emphasis>1.00</emphasis> inch diameter disbond or delamination in the bondline in the middle of skin.</para>
                    <para>The item could have up to <emphasis>1.00</emphasis> inch diameter disbond or delamination in the bondline in the middle of skin.</para>
                    <para>The item could have up to <emphasis>1.00</emphasis> inch diameter disbond or delamination in the bondline in the middle of skin.</para>
                    <para>The item could have up to <emphasis>1.00</emphasis> inch diameter disbond or delamination in the bondline in the middle of skin.</para>
                    <para>The item could have up to <emphasis>1.00</emphasis> inch diameter disbond or delamination in the bondline in the middle of skin.</para>
                    <para>The item could have up to <emphasis>1.00</emphasis> inch diameter disbond or delamination in the bondline in the middle of skin.</para>
                    <para>The item could have up to <emphasis>1.00</emphasis> inch diameter disbond or delamination in the bondline in the middle of skin.</para>
                    <para>The item could have up to <emphasis>1.00</emphasis> inch diameter disbond or delamination in the bondline in the middle of skin.</para>
                    <para>The item could have up to <emphasis>1.00</emphasis> inch diameter disbond or delamination in the bondline in the middle of skin.</para>
                </ftnote></para>
                </entry>
                <entry morerows="0" rotate="0" rowsep="0" valign="top">=</entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

And here is the abbreviated version of the stylesheet I'm using:

```
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:variable name="tableId">
                    <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="tableTitle">
                    <xsl:value-of select="child::title"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:for-each select="child::tgroup">
                    <xsl:variable name="numColumns" select="@cols"/>
                    <fo:table id="{$tableId}" table-layout="fixed" inline-progression-dimension="100%" margin-bottom="2mm" margin-top="2mm" table-omit-footer-at-break="true" fox:orphan-content-limit="2 * 1.2em"
                        fox:widow-content-limit="2 * 1.2em" keep-together.within-column="1">
                        <!-- Set up the table columns -->
                        <xsl:for-each select="colspec">
                            <!-- can be used if table layout has a fixed property... column-width="proportional-column-width(1)" -->
                            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)">
                                <xsl:attribute name="column-number">
                                    <xsl:number count="colspec"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                            </fo:table-column>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select=".">
                            <fo:table-header>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <xsl:if test="$numColumns &gt; '1'">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="number-columns-spanned">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="$numColumns"/>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-style="italic" text-indent="2mm" text-align="center" keep-with-next="always" margin-top="12pt" margin-bottom="2pt">
                                            <xsl:if test="ancestor::isolatep">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="margin-top">1mm</xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="margin-bottom">1mm</xsl:attribute>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$tableTitle"/>
                                            <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="table-title" retrieve-position-within-table="first-including-carryover"/>
                                        </fo:block>
                                        <xsl:if test="string-length($tableTitle) &gt; 75">
                                            <fo:block>
                                                <xsl:text>&#xa0; &#xa0;</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="child::thead">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="child::thead">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="child::row">
                                                <xsl:apply-templates select="self::row"/>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </fo:table-header>
                            <fo:table-footer keep-together.within-column="1">
                                <fo:table-row background-color="blue" keep-with-next="always">
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <xsl:if test="$numColumns &gt; '1'">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="number-columns-spanned">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="$numColumns"/>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <fo:block font-size="9pt" font-style="italic" text-indent="2mm" text-align="center" keep-with-next="always" margin-top="0mm" margin-bottom="0mm">
                                            <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="footer-continued" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page"/>
                                        </fo:block>
                                        <fo:block/>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <xsl:for-each select="child::tfoot/row">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="self::row"/>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <xsl:if test="count(ancestor::table//ftnote) &gt; 0">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::table//ftnote">
                                        <xsl:if test="not(ancestor::tfoot)">
                                            <fo:table-row>
                                                <fo:table-cell keep-with-next="always">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="number-columns-spanned">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="$numColumns"/>
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="border-left">solid</xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="border-right">solid</xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="border-bottom">solid</xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="border-width">.2mm</xsl:attribute>
                                                    <fo:block>
                                                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="footer-continued"/>
                                                    </fo:block>
                                                    <fo:block margin="0mm" padding="0mm">
                                                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="footer-continued"> (Continued)</fo:marker>
                                                    </fo:block>
                                                    <fo:block-container orphans="2" widows="2" margin-left=".7mm">
                                                        <fo:block font-size="8pt" margin-top=".7mm" margin-bottom=".7mm">
                                                            <fo:inline vertical-align="super" font-size="6pt">
                                                                <xsl:number count="ftnote" from="table" level="any" format="1"/>&#xa0;</fo:inline>
                                                            <xsl:for-each select="child::para">
                                                                <xsl:choose>
                                                                    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                                                                        <fo:inline padding-left="7.76mm" font-size="8pt">
                                                                            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::para"/>
                                                                        </fo:inline>
                                                                    </xsl:when>
                                                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                        <fo:block font-size="8pt" margin-left="8.40mm">
                                                                            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::para"/>
                                                                        </fo:block>
                                                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                                                </xsl:choose>
                                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                                        </fo:block>
                                                    </fo:block-container>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                            </fo:table-row>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </fo:table-footer>
                            <xsl:for-each select="child::tbody">
                                <fo:table-body>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="child::row">
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::row"/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </fo:table-body>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:table>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
<!-- table row template -->
<xsl:template name="tableRow" match="row">
    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always">
        <xsl:for-each select="entry">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::entry"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
<!-- template for table cells -->
<xsl:template name="tableCell" match="entry">
    <fo:table-cell text-align="left" padding-before="1mm" padding-left="1mm" language="en" country="US">
        <xsl:variable name="name_start" select="@namest"/>
        <xsl:variable name="name_end" select="@nameend"/>
        <xsl:variable name="colst">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$name_start">
                    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::tgroup/colspec">
                        <xsl:if test="@colname = $name_start">
                            <xsl:number count="colspec" from="tgroup"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:number value="0"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="colend">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($name_end) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::tgroup/colspec">
                        <xsl:if test="@colname = $name_end">
                            <xsl:number count="colspec" from="tgroup"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:number value="0"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="colspan">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$colst and $colend">
                    <xsl:value-of select="number($colend) - number($colst) + 1"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:number value="0"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="rowspan">
            <xsl:if test="@morerows &gt; '0'">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(ancestor::tgroup/thead) and (ancestor::tbody/row/entry/@morerows)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@morerows + 1"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="ancestor::tgroup/thead">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@morerows + 1"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@morerows + 1"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- Decide which attributes to set for spanning -->
        <xsl:if test="$colspan and $rowspan">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="number($colspan) &gt; 1 and number($rowspan) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:attribute name="number-columns-spanned">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$colspan"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="number-rows-spanned">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$rowspan"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$colspan">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="number($colspan) &gt; 1">
                    <!-- just COLSPAN  -->
                    <xsl:attribute name="number-columns-spanned">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$colspan"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$rowspan &gt; '0'">
                <!-- just rowspan  -->
                <xsl:attribute name="number-rows-spanned">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$rowspan"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:if test="ancestor::tgroup/thead">
                    <xsl:attribute name="overflow">visible</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <!-- Set up cell borders -->
        <xsl:attribute name="border">solid</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="border-width">.2mm</xsl:attribute>
        <!-- Set appropriate attributes based on table section -->
        <xsl:if test="ancestor::tbody">
            <xsl:attribute name="display-align">auto</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="ancestor::thead">
            <xsl:attribute name="display-align">center</xsl:attribute>
            <fo:block>
                <fo:marker marker-class-name="table-title"/>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="ancestor::tfoot">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:marker marker-class-name="footer-continued"/>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block margin="0mm" padding="0mm">
                <fo:marker marker-class-name="footer-continued"> (Continued)</fo:marker>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:if>
        <fo:block>
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="table-title">&#xa0;(Continued) </fo:marker>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block-container orphans="2" widows="2">
            <fo:block language="en" country="US" font-size="10pt" wrap-option="wrap">
                <xsl:if test="ancestor::thead">
                    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="ancestor::tfoot or count(ancestor::table//ftnote) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">9pt</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="self::para">
                            <fo:block font-size="10pt" text-align="left" wrap-option="wrap" orphans="2" widows="2">
                                <xsl:if test="ancestor::tfoot or count(ancestor::table//ftnote) &gt; 0">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">9pt</xsl:attribute>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="self::para"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="self::text() and not(../para)">
                            <xsl:if test="string-length(self::text()) &gt; 0">
                                <xsl:value-of select="self::text()"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <!-- This is dangerous, is there a better way?? -->
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
    </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="footnote" match="ftnote">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ancestor::entry and not(ancestor::tfoot)">
            <!--just put supscript number in for tables unless it is already in the tfoot section -->
            <fo:inline vertical-align="super" font-size="6pt" padding-left=".5mm" margin-left=".7mm">
                <xsl:number count="ftnote" from="table" level="any" format="1"/>
            </fo:inline>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="ancestor::tfoot">
            <fo:block orphans="2" widows="2" keep-together.within-page="always" padding-bottom="1mm">
                <fo:inline vertical-align="super" margin-left=".7mm" font-size="6pt">
                    <xsl:number count="ftnote" from="table" level="any" format="1"/>&#xa0;</fo:inline>
                <xsl:for-each select="child::para">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                            <fo:inline padding-left="7.76mm" font-size="8pt">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="self::para"/>
                            </fo:inline>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <fo:block font-size="8pt" margin-left="8.40mm">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="self::para"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:footnote keep-together.within-page="always">
                <fo:inline vertical-align="super" font-size="9pt" margin-right="6mm"> &#xa0;<xsl:number count="ftnote" level="any" format="1"/>&#xa0; </fo:inline>
                <fo:footnote-body>
                    <fo:block font-size="9pt">
                        <fo:inline vertical-align="super" margin-right="2mm">
                            <xsl:number count="ftnote" level="any" format="1"/>&#xa0; </fo:inline>
                        <xsl:for-each select="para">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::para">
                                    <fo:block font-size="9pt" text-align="left">
                                        <xsl:call-template name="para"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="self::para"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:footnote-body>
            </fo:footnote>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm trying to use the retrieve-table-marker in the fo:table-footer section to retrieve the table title when the footer breaks, but the page never breaks. I've tried all combinations of retrieve-postion on the marker with no changes. I've also tried all combinations of the retrieve-position-within-table attribute, which I don't believe is implemented in the latest version of FOP anyway according to: [Apache FOP compliance doc](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html)

I don't understand why FOP will break the table in the tbody section but not the tfoot section? Any suggestions or comments would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I'm editing this question to ask if there is something I'm not being clear about here or missing information that would allow someone to answer this question or point me in a direction. I have tried setting the overflow attribute to visible on various constructs within the table with no effect. I am also adding a screen shot that shows the problem in the pdf.
[image]

Comment: In further testing of this problem, I have created a basic table with a large tfoot section containing simple elements and it seems that the table breaks only in the table-body, but not in the table-footer sections. According to the documentation I have read it should break in both sections. I'm curious about what attribute or construct I'm missing to implement this.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the similar issue, but with table header.

Comment: Not as cleanly as I would like. It appears to be due to the incomplete implementation of these constructs in FOP. I haven't worked on it in quite awhile, about 6 months, so I don't know if they have updated FOP since I encountered this. I ended up doing some layout trickery with the xslt and the way I laid out the table constructs.